# angularjs: main page's UI blocked while loading second page which is opened into new tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Idea is to add `ctrl + click` functionality to table row `<tr>`. When user clicks on table row while holding `ctrl` button it opens details page in new tab.

This is table row's template:

```
 <tr class="clickable-row" ng-repeat="row in books track by row.id" ng-click="testCtrl.navigate($event, row.id)">
```

This is `ng-click` function:

```
function navigate($event, rowId) {
  const url = `/books/${rowId}`;
  // on ctrl||cmd + click open details in new tab
  if ($event.ctrlKey || $event.metaKey) {
    $window.open(url, '_blank');
    return;
  }
 $location.path(url);
}
```

**Problem**: when I open details view into new tab it's blocking main page's UI while details view is loading into new tab.

Just created small test fiddle with plain JavaScript and it's working fine, when you click "Open new tab" button while holding `ctrl` key, it's opening a new tab with same page and in the same time you can click again on this button and it's not blocked.

Here is the [js-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/91580gvq/16/)

How I understand it, there could be problem into AngularJS and same domain loading into new tab. Tested this same case with `$window.open('https://www.google.lv/', '_blank');` and in this time it's not blocking main pages UI.
What is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was because both tabs were running with same process and that cause UI blocking.

Found a solution for this.

> Adding a rel="noopener" attribute prevents the new page from being able to access the window.opener property and will ensure it runs in a separate process.

```
function navigate($event, rowId) {
  const url = `/books/${rowId}`;
  // on ctrl||cmd + click open details in new tab
  if ($event.ctrlKey || $event.metaKey) {
    const link = $document[0].createElement('a');
    $document[0].body.appendChild(link);
    link.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    link.setAttribute('rel', 'noopener');
    link.setAttribute('href', url);
    link.click();
    link.remove();
    return;
  }
 $location.path(url);
}
```

**Working on major browsers except Safari.**